Integral of multidimensional Dirac-delta function with substitution and practical handling of Minkowski content measure
I am working with an integral with respect to a 2-D Dirac delta function of the form
$$\int_a^b \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  f(x,y,z)\delta\left(\begin{bmatrix}g_1(x,y,z)\\g_2(x,y,z)\end{bmatrix}\right) dzdydx$$
I have a parameterization $x(z),\:y(z)$ on which the delta function argument is zero.
I am familiar with the Wikipedia article on the delta function, and the associated formula
$$\int \delta(g(\textbf{x}))f(\textbf{x})d\textbf{x}=\int_{g^{-1}(0)} \frac{f(\textbf{x})}{|\nabla g(\textbf{x})|}d\sigma(\textbf{x})$$
where $\sigma(\textbf{x})$ is the "Minkowski content measure". Intuition dictates that the extension of this to my case would be (with $\textbf{x}=(x,y,z)$)
$$\int \delta(\textbf{g}(\textbf{x}))f(\textbf{x})d\textbf{x}=\int_{\textbf{g}^{-1}([0,0])}\frac{f(\textbf{x})}{\left|\frac{dg_i}{dx_i}\right|_{\text{norm}}}d\sigma(\textbf{x})$$
Or if we treat $z$ as a parameter with $\textbf{x}=(x,y)$,
$$\int_a^b \int \delta(\textbf{g}(\textbf{x}))f(\textbf{x})d\textbf{x}dz=\int_a^b\frac{f(\textbf{x})}{\left|\text{det}\frac{dg_i}{dx_i}\Big|_{i=1,2}\right|}\Bigg|_{x=x(z),y=y(z)}dz$$
I have a couple of questions. First, what is the rubber-meets-the-road definition of the Minkowski content measure? If I want to set up this integral for a numerical solution in $z$, what do I put on the $\sigma$?
In the second case where $z$ is treated as a parameter, do I need a $\sigma$ factor of some kind? Is it just the surface area element of my parameterization of the zero-set of g?
Second, I was hoping to sanity-check the formulas from intuition presented here, and am seeking practical sources for methodology and reference.
Many thanks!

The appendix of the paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.06895  has a very excellent self-contained appendix on $\delta$ calculus. You need how ever to know some basic differential geometry, integration on smooth manifolds in particular.

@Medo Thanks, I appreciate it. This appears to have the information I'm looking for locked within; however my differential geometry, particularly notational knowledge, is a little lacking so it's a little terse for me. Do you mind if I ask you a few questions to help guide me towards studying this?

@NickS Can you share the source of the problem?

@SineoftheTime, Basically, it's equation 2.1.29b in the link below. There is a delta function of a vector, which for practical reasons we move to polar coordinates. This makes a delta function of a vector of scalar functions. The second delta function involving omega can be handled independently.
https://www.weizmann.ac.il/chembiophys/lvov/sites/chemphys.lvov/files/uploads/books/KolmogorovSpectraOfTurbulence/002_kst-chapter2.pdf.
